# How do I enter an RTL answer?

Tags: support, hebrew, display, formatting

How do I tell the website that my text should be formatted RTL?

I tried wrapping the answer in `<DIV dir=rtl>` but that got rid of all formatting in the answer - and didn't fix the problem.

It's mainly a problem for the punctuation, making sure it's on the correct side of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `&rlm` to the end of a line, with a `;` to close the command.

For instance:

`שלום עליכם.&rlm;`

שלום עליכם.‏

Thanks, msh210, for teaching me.